# How to Verify an Email Address in Python Using smtplib

Tags: python, email, email-validation, smtplib

I have been trying to verify an email address entered by the user in my program. The code I currently have is:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP()
server.connect()
server.set_debuglevel(True)
try:
    server.verify(email)
except Exception:
    return False
finally:
    server.quit()
```

However when I run it I get:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

So what I am asking is how do i verify an email address using the smtp module? I want to check whether the email address actually exists.

Comment: You need to elaborate on what "verify" means. Do you want to check if the address is well-formed, or that it exists?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/blinks/47987

Answer (score 17):

Here's a simple way to verify emails. This is minimally modified code from [this link](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Email-Verification/Python-Email-Verification-Script). The first part will check if the email address is well-formed, the second part will ping the SMTP server with that address and see if it gets a success code (250) back or not. That being said, this isn't failsafe -- depending how this is set up sometimes every email will be returned as valid. So you should still send a verification email.

```
email_address = 'example@example.com'

#Step 1: Check email
#Check using Regex that an email meets minimum requirements, throw an error if not
addressToVerify = email_address
match = re.match('^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$', addressToVerify)

if match == None:
    print('Bad Syntax in ' + addressToVerify)
    raise ValueError('Bad Syntax')

#Step 2: Getting MX record
#Pull domain name from email address
domain_name = email_address.split('@')[1]

#get the MX record for the domain
records = dns.resolver.query(domain_name, 'MX')
mxRecord = records[0].exchange
mxRecord = str(mxRecord)

#Step 3: ping email server
#check if the email address exists

# Get local server hostname
host = socket.gethostname()

# SMTP lib setup (use debug level for full output)
server = smtplib.SMTP()
server.set_debuglevel(0)

# SMTP Conversation
server.connect(mxRecord)
server.helo(host)
server.mail('me@domain.com')
code, message = server.rcpt(str(addressToVerify))
server.quit()

# Assume 250 as Success
if code == 250:
    print('Y')
else:
    print('N')
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you @verybadatthis.  Could also add the import statements and adjust resolver (wasn't able to use **dns.resolver**)?  `import re;
from dns import resolver;
import socket;
import smtplib;`

Comment: This is not working for emails other than Gmail Id's.. How to check other email domains like hotmail yahoo etc

Answer (score 0):

The server name isn't defined properly along with the port. Depending on how you have your SMTP server you might need to use the login function.

```
server = smtplib.SMTP(str(SERVER), int(SMTP_PORT))
server.connect()
server.set_debuglevel(True)
try:
    server.verify(email)
except Exception:
    return False
finally:
    server.quit()
```

Comment: How do we know port of smtp of client or third party email address ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the smtp host (server) in the `SMTP` construct. This depends on the email domain. eg for a gmail address you would need something like `gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com`.

The `server.verify` which is a SMTP `VRFY` probably isnt what you want though. Most servers disable it.

You might want to look at a service like [Real Email](https://isitarealemail.com) which has guide for python. [How to Validate Email Address in python](https://docs.isitarealemail.com/how-to-validate-email-addresses-in-python).